# Docusign select signature provider from accounts api object

Tags: python, docusignapi

When I make a call to the Docusign API for `list_signature_providers` I receive an accounts_api object that has all of my signature provider options and information. I can pass this object as the `recipient_signature_providers` to my `Signers` object in the document envelope. However, it will only set the default signer option.

This is what my accounts object contains:

```
accounts_api = AccountsApi(self.api_client)
providers = accounts_api.list_signature_providers(self._json_token_info['api_account_id'])
print(providers)
{'signature_providers': [{'is_required': 'false',
                          'priority': '0',
                          'signature_provider_display_name': 'DS Electronic',
                          'signature_provider_id': '0',
                          'signature_provider_name': 'universalsignaturepen_imageonly',
                          'signature_provider_options_metadata': None,
                          'signature_provider_required_options': None},
                         {'is_required': 'false',
                          'priority': '1',
                          'signature_provider_display_name': 'GlobalSign - '
                                                             'Digital Signing '
                                                             'Service (DSS) - '
                                                             'Production',
                          'signature_provider_id': '73',
                          'signature_provider_name': 'globalsign_tsp',
                          'signature_provider_options_metadata': None,
                          'signature_provider_required_options': None}]}
```

If I try to print provider[0], I get a TypeError: 'AccountSignatureProviders' object is not subscriptable. So I can't pass that to the `Signer` object.

How do I choose a signature provider to use when passing the `accounts_api` object to the `Signers` object?

Comment: What are you trying to do? what is your goal here? to do what?

Comment: The goal is to swap between the 'DS Electronic' and the 'GlobalSign' signature provider as required for the documents I'm working with.

Comment: are you using the developer account? does it have this option when you use it, not from API, but from the web UI?

Comment: yes, I'm all set up on the developer side. What I need is to figure out how to set the signature choice during the envelope creation process. I have already tested the process without the parameter (Which is the default when you don't have a TSP set up). The signature provider list would not have a TSP if I had not set up access with Docusign already.

Comment: You will have to reach out to customer service/support to help set this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`providers.to_dict()` converts the AccountSignatureProviders object to a dictionary at which point you can iterate through the signature providers via `json.dumps(providers['signature_providers'][1])`.

There is another option provided by [this documentation](https://docusign.github.io/docusign-esign-python-client/docusign_esign/models/account_signature_providers.html#AccountSignatureProviders) for the AccountSignatureProviders object. You can index the providers with `AccountSignatureProviders.signature_providers[x]`

From here you can set the signature provider to the Signer object by putting the indexed provider in a list to provide to the recipient_signature_providers parameter: `recipient_signature_providers=[AccountSignatureProviders.signature_providers[x]]`.